# Make asynchronous call inside loop until a value is found

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to do several calls inside a loop to an asynchronous API until the value that I want (`true` in this case) is returned. The issue is that I don't want to keep looping after that value is found and I don't want to execute the lines after the loop without the value returned from it...but so far I can't get that working. I think I'm doing something wrong here, but "I can't get the whole picture".

```
function isSelected(element, callback) {
  // This is a little bit confusing for me...can I just get the value from
  // getDataAsync without using isSelected function?
  Office.select(element).getDataAsync(function (asyncResult) {
    var result = true;

    // some logic here that may change 'result'
    callback(result);
  });
}

function delete(elements) {
  var index = -1;

  for (var i = 0, (i < elements.length) && (index < 0); i++) {
    isSelected(elements[i], function(result) {
      if (result) { index = i; }; // ...and I don't want to keep "looping"
    });
  }
  // I want to execute these lines after the for-loop is done
  // ...do something with the "correct" index value
}
```

Comment: Why don't you choose "accept answer" something missing?

Comment: @Amina There is a condition there: `if (result) { index = i; }`...and after that I can't execute anymore otherwise I would potentially get more `true` values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [Kriskowal's Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)? There's a nice function called `Q#allSettled`:

```
Q.allSettled(promises)
.then(function (results) {
    results.forEach(function (result) {
        if (result.state === "fulfilled") {
            var value = result.value;
        } else {
            var reason = result.reason;
        }
    });
});
```

So basically this is how it would work in your case:

```
var promises = [];

for(/* conditions */) {
  promises.push(/* async call which returns a promise */);
}

Q.allSettled(promises).then(function(results) {
    results.forEach(function (result) {
        var value;

        if (result.state === "fulfilled") {
            value = result.value;

            // do something with "value"
        }
    });
});
```

`allSettled` just makes sure the `then` will be executed regardless of whether or not the promise was successful or not, and you can check the value of the object you retrieve from your async call.

Answer (score 1):

## **I am recommending three ways to doing it.**

- Using just JavaScript.
- Using Async library.
- Using underscore library.

Here you can see the javascript implementation:

You can do something like that:
You need to track home many times, you call the function, and how many times the callback happened

```
function delete(elements) {
  var index = -1;

  var stack=0;
  for (var i = 0, (i < elements.length) && (index < 0); i++) {
    stack++         // Go up on each loop
    isSelected(elements[i], function() {
      stack--;     //Go down each callback
      index = i;
      if(stack==0) afterAllFinish()   //When it return to 0 mean all callback have finished
    });
  }

  function afterAllFinish(){
    // I want to execute these lines after the for-loop is done
    // ...do something with the "correct" index value
  }
}
```

## Using other libraries:

1. Please take a look at http://underscorejs.org/#after for the underscore way to solve it.
2. Please take a look at https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel to see the async way to solve it.